# User cannot connect to Exchange Server 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

While configuring Office Outlook 2007 in the workstations to access my Exchange Server 2010, I stepped in a problem.

None of the workstations are part of the domain, but they can access their Exchange mailboxes by providing username and password nevertheless.

One of them though, fails to connect to the server. It doesn't even ask for a password, it just says there was a problem with the connection.

In this workstation in particular, the local username and password are the same as in the domain, the only difference is the full username: **station\username** against **domain\username**. It led me to believe this must be the cause of such conflict.

Is there some way I can make my server understands **anything\username** as **domain\username** in order to workaround this problem? I read somewhere it was possible, but I can no longer find this article anywhere.

Comment: Check the "always prompt for logon credentials" checkbox on the Security tab in the account settings. Then launch Outlook and make sure you use the domain\username or the UPN. If you're able to logon successfully then you can uncheck that box and check the save password box the next time you launch Outlook.

Comment: If the user types in `domain\username` or `username@domain.tld` ... then that's not the problem.  (I highly doubt that's the problem in any case, as a mismatched user principal name (UPN) is a will return a standard `incorrect username or password error`, not a "connection problem" error.)  My guess would be authentication type - NTLM not being accepted by the server, or a Kerberos authentication issue from that workstation.  Whatever the cause, you'll need to dig deeper than the apparent username and password similarities.  Check the logs.

Comment: @joeqwerty - you should make that an answer.